# How can I update the response of a slash command using a button?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

Using discord.js, I created a slash command that takes in a string option, uses it to query an API, and replies with the result in an embed.

There is a button attached to the reply that updates the data with an updated query.

How can I get the option used in the slash command when I am interacting with the button?

I have tried to send the string option through the action row builder, set the button customId with the string option, and even send it as part of the embed. All of those solutions do not work correctly and seems gimmicky.

I wonder if there is a way to fetch an interaction using its id and get the string option that way?

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  const search = interaction.options.getString("search");
  const pairs = await getQuery(search);
  const refreshButton = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId(search)
    .setLabel("Refresh")
    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

  const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents([refreshButton]);
  const embed = makeEmbed(pairs[0]);

  if (pairs.length > 0) {
    interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      components: [row],
    });
  } else {
    interaction.reply(
      `No results for search term ${search}. Please check your query and try again.`
    );
  }
},

// NEED ACCESS TO THE STRING OPTION search IN THIS FUNCTION
async refresh(interaction) {
  const pairs = await getQuery(interaction.customId);
  const embed = makeEmbed(pairs[0]);

  console.log(interaction.customId);
  if (pairs.length > 0) {
    interaction.update({ embeds: [embed] });
  } else {
    interaction.update(
      `No results for search term ${search}. Please check your query and try again.`
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried so far? How do the things you tried not work? What makes them seem gimmicky?

Comment: @asportnoy Setting the customId to the string option does work but I want to be able to use the customId for it's intended use. The other two solutions just do not work.

Comment: [message.interaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/InteractionResponse) in discord.js does not have options in them and I don't see any other way to. If you don't want to use customId for that, I think the only other option is to store it in an external database.

Comment: @asportnoy the problem with using customId is, how would I differentiate between buttons?

Comment: You could separate the different parts with a certain character. For example, `actionName-argToAction`. You could even format it like a query string  to make parsing easier.